# Moq verifying parameter with multiple boolean conditions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I'm trying to make my tests as readable and maintainable as I can and I'd like to have this form of verification of parameter object passed to the mock I've supplied to SUT.

```
_emailHelperMock.Verify(eh => eh.OnMailCreated(
            It.Is<MailMessage>(WithBodyContaining(enrolment) && SentTo(Test.CustomerAddress))));
```

But I didn't yet find a solution how to do this since I get the compilation error:

```
Error   CS0019  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Expression<Func<MailMessage, bool>>' and 'Expression<Func<MailMessage, bool>>'
```

Syntactic sugar methods I've used above are defined in the following way:

```
    private static Expression<Func<MailMessage, bool>> WithBodyContaining(Enrolment enrolment)
    {
        return mail => mail.Body.Contains(enrolment.Title) && mail.Body.Contains(enrolment.Date);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<MailMessage, bool>> SentTo(string address)
    {
        return mail => mail.To.ToString().Contains(address);
    }
```

I can make a single method e.g. `WithBodyContainingEnrolmentAndSentToAddress(enrolment, address)`, but I'd rather have the form with multiple boolean checks I've stated above.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your methods to return `bool`s instead of `Expression<Func<MailMessage, bool>>`s then you can combine them and in my opinion they will be clearer anyway. For example:

```
_emailHelperMock.Verify(eh => eh.OnMailCreated(It.Is<MailMessage>(mail => WithBodyContaining(mail, enrolment) && SentTo(mail, Test.CustomerAddress)

private static bool WithBodyContaining(MailMessage mail, Enrolment enrolment)
{
    return mail.Body.Contains(enrolment.Title) && mail.Body.Contains(enrolment.Date);
}

private static bool SentTo(MailMessage mail, string address)
{
    return mail.To.ToString().Contains(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine the expressions:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var param = expr1.Parameters[0];
            if (ReferenceEquals(param, expr2.Parameters[0]))
            {
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), param);
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, Expression.Invoke(expr2, param)), param);
        }
```